How can I explain the huge difference between validation and test errors in DNN
I'm new to DNNs and trying to see how they work on cifar10 dataset (without using Convolutional layers). I'm using 2 different architectures:
1.
def create_model(n_layers=5, n_neurons=100, shape=[32, 32, 3]):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=shape))
    for _ in range(n_layers):
        model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons,
                                 activation="selu",
                                 kernel_initializer="lecun_normal"))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam()
    
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model




model_bn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

   model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[32, 32, 3]))
   model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

   for _ in range(5):
       model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(100,
                                 kernel_initializer="he_normal",
                                 kernel_constraint=tf.keras.constraints.max_norm(1.)))
       model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
       model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation("elu"))
   model_bn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))

   optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(learning_rate=1e-3)
   model_bn.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["accuracy"])

Those models use the same callbacks to prevent overfitting and training for a long amount of epochs:
early_stopping_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=6, monitor="val_loss")
   lr_scheduler_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.5, patience=3)
   checkpoint_cb = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("my_cifar10_model_v1.keras", save_best_only=True)
   callbacks = [early_stopping_cb, checkpoint_cb, tensorboard_cb, lr_scheduler_cb]

But at the end of fitting, I get huge difference between training and validation errors (around 10-18%), which I can explain only by overfitting, however checkpoint_cb believes that this is the best model, regardless of the fact of overfitting. Do I stick to these results or I need to get the model that has lower difference in training and validation accuracies, consequently lower final validation accuracy. If so, is there a callback that stops when training accuracy increases, while validation error stays apporximately the same?
I tried setting different learning rates and patience parameters, but nothing seem to help.

Hi, I’ve reviewed your code and noticed a huge difference between the
training and testing errors. To address this, I suggest implementing data
augmentation techniques. Additionally, consider performing hyperparameter
tuning using Keras Tuner to optimize the model. To see how to use Keras Tuner
with CNN networks, please refer to this gist.
